# Routing to Vuepress Install within Laravel App

Tags: laravel, vuepress

Trying to figure out how to access my Vuepress install within my Laravel project. Currently it sits here:

```
project
  |
  |--app
  |--docs
  |--public
```

The Vuepress install is based on the intro guide from the site, so that when I run `yarn docs:build` it puts all the static files in `docs/.vuepress/dist/`. The dev server for Vuepress works great.

What I want is to be able to access this install from `https://app.project.com/docs`, but no combination of `.htaccess` or routes in `web.php` is getting me there.

I can move the contents of the `/dist` folder into `/public`, rename it `'docs', and do this:

```
Route::get('/docs/{documentation}', function($documentation) {
  return File::get(public_path() . '/docs/'.$documentation);
});
```

but it only works if I manually put index.html at the end of each URL, and even then it doesn't serve up the same results I'm seeing in the dev server.

There's an easy way to do this I'm missing isn't there?

Comment: So this was super easy, and ridiculous when you think about it. Anything in `/public` folder will be accessed without any mod whatsoever--just can't see it locally. Change `config.js` to add `base: '/docs/'` and `dest:'./public/docs'` to build Vuepress in /docs folder and that's it.